# Visual Studio: C++ Project Include Paths sharing over Repository

Tags: c++, visual-studio, svn, linker, include-path

I was wondering how should I add my library include paths and linker paths in Visual Studio so that when I add my project to a repository, another developer checking out my project would not need to go through all the include paths and change them for his own machine. So, I am kind of looking at something like `${MY_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_INCLUDE_PATH}\tbb\include` and `${MY_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_LINKER_PATH}\tbb\lib\ia32\vc11` so that someone accessing the project can just change `MY_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_INCLUDE_PATH` and `MY_THIRD_PARTY_LIB_LINKER_PATH` and everything works as intended. Can somebody suggest a best practice around this or may be how to accomplish what I just described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VisualStudio 2012 I use [Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So if you go to the Propery Manager you Add a new Project Property Sheet to you project.  From there, a couple of things can be set

User Macros - We create a macro here and put in a path for our environment.  We crate a Macro called CUSTOM_DEBUG_PATHS, and then in the project we set the Debugging->Environment to `path=$(PLA_DEBUG_PATHS);$(PATH)`

The other thing that we do in the Project Property Sheet is change our Include and Library directories. We have everyone use relative paths, but you could put in an environment variable or something in here so that everyone could use the same file.

Comment: This unfortunately is not working for me. I am still getting red lines all over my include's. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you changed? For includes you need to update the Include and Library directories.

Comment: Yeah. I changed the include and library paths as $(CUSTOM_LIB_PATH)tbb\include where CUSTOM_LIB_PATH is macro containing my directory where I store all my third party libraries (Same for corresponding lib path).

Comment: is CUSTOM_LIB_PATH defined somewhere else, or is that an Env variable?

Comment: It was defined as a macro and I also tried Env variable when macro was not working. I realized that I needed a '\' in the path (Macro as well as Env variable) which I did not provide initially. In other words, `$(CUSTOM_LIB_PATH)tbb\include` would not work if $(CUSTOM_LIB_PATH) does not have a '\' at the end. Thanks for the help. :)